# Simple Javascript Form Validate Length. (element.value.length<2)

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I am quite new to the javascript language, and I'm having some problem with form validation on a simple html input form:

Everything was working fine, right before I started messing around with the `CheckLength` function on `UserName`. I would like the form to NOT "`return true;`" on submit, if the `UserName`'s length is less than 2 (`element.value.length < 2`).

Right now it is still redirecting me to http://google.dk, if I fill in all the inputs and click Send (Even though the `UserName` is less than 2).

**HTML:**

```
<form name="form1" action="http://google.dk"  method="POST" id="form1">

                <label for="name">username:</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" /><br>
                <label for="phone">Phone:</label>
                <input type="text" name="phone" id="telephone" /><br>
                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="emailadress" /><br>
                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input type="text" name="password" id="Password" /><br>
                <label for="description">Description:</label>
                <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="description" id="description"></textarea><br>

                <input type="submit" id="btn" name="btn" value="Send" />

        <p id="errormessage"></p>
</form>
```

**JAVSCRIPT:**

```
window.onload = function () {

//HTML form variables
var form1 = document.getElementById("form1");
//HTML inputs variables
var UserName = document.getElementById("username");
var Phone = document.getElementById("telephone");
var eMail = document.getElementById("emailadress");
var PassWord = document.getElementById("Password");
var Description = document.getElementById("description");

// Functions
var checkLength = function(element) {
    if(element.value.length < 2){
        alert("Brugernavnet du har indtastet er for kort! Mindst 2 tegn.");
    }
};

UserName.onblur = function(){
    if(checkLength(UserName)){
    return false;
    }
};

form1.onsubmit = function(){

    //Username
    if( UserName.value == "" ){
        alert( "Skriv venligst et brugernavn!" );
        UserName.focus() ; //Sætter fokus på det bestemte inputfelt.
        return false; //return false; gør at den sender dataen videre ved onSumbit.
    }

    //Phone
    if( Phone.value == "" ){
        alert( "Udfyld venligst dit telefonnummer!" );
        Phone.focus() ;
        return false;
    }

    //Email
    if( eMail.value == "" ){
        alert( "Udfyld venligst din mailadresse!" );
        eMail.focus() ;
        return false;
    }

    //Password
    if( PassWord.value == "" ){
        alert( "Skriv venligst en adgangskode!" );
        PassWord.focus() ;
        return false;
    }

    //Description
    if( Description.value == "" ){
        alert( "Lav venligst en beskrivelse af dig selv!" );
        Description.focus() ;
        return false;
    }

    if(checkLength(UserName)){
    return false;
    }

    alert( "Succes!" ); //Hvis alle overstående felter er udfyldt, vil der komme en alertbox op med teksten "Succes!".
    return( true ); //Hvis alle overstående felter er udfyldt, vil den sende dataen videre ved onSubmit.
};


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're returning true `onsubmit`, no matter what, so it will always submit.

Have a look at the very end of your code:

```
return( true );
```

You'll have to do an `else if` for each of your error checks, or better yet, if I was you, I'd create a variable called `error` or something, that will only be 0 if there are no errors.

You could do it like this:

```
form1.onsubmit = function(){

var error = 0; // set this here
```

Then inside each `if` statement checking for errors, you could set it to 1.

```
//Username
if( UserName.value == "" ){
    //...
    error = 1;
}
```

Then at the very end, replace this...

```
alert( "Succes!" );
return( true );
```

...with this...

```
if (error == 0) {
    alert( "Succes!" );
    return( true );
}
```

**[Here is a demo you can fiddle with.](http://jsfiddle.net/PvD77/)**

**EDITED:** As pointed out by @user3091574 in their answer, there is another problem with your code: your `checkLength` variable does not return *true* or *false* therefore checking it like `if (checkLength(UserName))` is not going to return anything (or will always be false, I believe - did not test this part). Consequently, you'll have to add *true* if the *length* is more than 2 and *false* if it's not, then it will work.

```
var checkLength = function(element) {
    if(element.value.length < 2){
        alert("Brugernavnet du har indtastet er for kort! Mindst 2 tegn.");
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
};
```

Additionally, you'll have to change the following checks, like this, as now if `checkLength(UserName)` returns *true*, we're happy to submit the form:

```
UserName.onblur = function(){
    if(checkLength(UserName)){
        return true;
    }
};

// ...

if(checkLength(UserName)){
    alert( "Succes!" ); //Hvis alle overstående felter er udfyldt, vil der komme en alertbox op med teksten "Succes!".
    return true; //Hvis alle overstående felter er udfyldt, vil den sende dataen videre ved onSubmit.
}
```

**[Here is the updated fiddle demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/PvD77/1/)**

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It wasn't quite working 100% (it still passed if I filled in all the inputs (even if "username < 2". But at the very end, I changed it to the following which seems to work:
    if(checkLength(UserName)){
        alert( "Succes!" ); 
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

Answer (score 0):

You must return "false" in your code so that the submit action won't be triggered.

The code must look like this:

```
var checkLength = function(element) {
    if(element.value.length < 2){
        alert("Brugernavnet du har indtastet er for kort! Mindst 2 tegn.");
        return false;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

your Check method doesn't return anything (it only pops an alert box)

 so code inside the if statement will never be executed because checkLength doesn't return anything    
change your check method

```
var checkLength = function(element) {
if(element.value.length < 2){
   return false;
}else{
   return true;
 }
};
```

Comment: he's already doing that here: `if(checkLength(UserName)){ return false; }` (see towards the end...)

Comment: @webeno but method checkLength(userName) is not returning anything(true or false)